# Postgresql numeric and decimal is automatically rounding off

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgresql-11

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ttable (
    tcol decimal(9,7)
);
```

```
insert into ttable(tcol) values(17.4604786);
```

the value is getting stored as `17.46`

Happens the same if I use decimal/numeric type

I am using 

**PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42), 64-bit.** 

**Tool**
SQL Workbench/J Build 124 (2018-08-20 22:43)
 
Java version: 1.8.0_211 (64 bit).

**Connection info:**
Product Name: PostgreSQL
Product Version: 11.2
Product Info: 11.2
Driver Name: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
Driver Class: org.postgresql.Driver
Driver Version: 42.2.6
Isolation Level: READ COMMITTED
Workbench DBID: postgresql

Comment: How are you getting the value? Which client tool?

Comment: @McNets Updated my question with info on tools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be the default behaviour of SQL Workbench, have a look at this article:

[How do I change the resolution or scale of decimal data type on SQL Workbench.](https://mapr.com/support/s/article/How-do-I-change-the-scale-of-decimal-data-type-on-SQL-Workbench?language=en_US)

Quoted from the article:

> Normally, SQL Workbench doesn't display the decimal data with the full
>   scale. By default the scale is 2. We can change the scale by the
>   setting.

> **Solution**
>
> 1. Open Data formatting settings. SQLWorkBench -> Preferences ->Data formatting
> 2. Change Decimal digits The default is 2. In this case, it should be at least 11.

And according to SQL Workbench manual about [Data formating](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/options.html#options-data-formatting):

> **Decimal digits**
>
> Define the maximum number of digits which will be displayed for
>   numeric columns. This only affects the display of the number, not the
>   storage or retrieval. Internally they are still stored as the DBMS
>   returned them. To see the internal value, leave the mouse cursor over
>   the cell. The tool tip which is displayed will contain the number as
>   it was returned by the JDBC driver. When exporting data or copying it
>   to the clipboard, the real value will be used.
>
> **If this value is set to 0 (zero) values will be display with as many digits as available.**

(Bold is mine)

Comment: you can always double check easily using one of the fiddles - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bb76b/1

Comment: @McNets thank you.

Comment: @SQLRaptor thank you for introducing me to sqlfiddle

Comment: I'm glad to help, there are more fiddles like [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and [rextester](https://rextester.com/)